# SSIS ‘Data Flow Task’ No records in flat file destination

Tags: ssis

Please forgive my initial posting being a question instead of a solution.

I’ve got two SSIS packages that basically do the same thing.  The last step of both is a ‘Data Flow Task’ that queries the database and attempts to write the results to a flat file.  One of the packages builds the flat file correctly, the other builds the file but doesn’t populate it with any records.  Running SQL Server 2008 R2.

This is in a University setting involving transferring degree_codes and demographics between two systems.  The degree_code package is functioning, the demographics isn’t.  Both ‘Data Flow Tasks’ consist of an OLE DB Source linked to a Flat File Destination (tab delimitated text).  Both packages display the correct data set when previewing the OLE DB Source.

In the Flat File Destination, the mappings are correct in both packages.  However, when previewing the data, the degree details display correctly, but there are no records in the demographic preview.  That’s also true when looking at the connection managers.  And when the packages run, the degree_codes file is correct while the demographics file only contains a header.  It seems there is a problem with the link between the OLE DB Source and the Flat File Destination

Both packages run with only a warning about shared global memory impacting performance.  I’ve deleted and rebuilt the non-functioning Data Flow Task and connection managers without fixing the problem.  At this point I am at a loss of which direction to go and don’t know how to diagnose the problem.  Have any of you folks run into a similar situation or do you have any suggestions how to chase it down.  I’d be grateful for any solutions.

Comment: If you are executing the packages using BIDS/Visual Studio, when the Data Flow goes "yellow", inside the task there should be an indicator of how many rows are being sent from the your source (OLE DB Source). What you are describing sounds like something - either your source query or a transformation between the source and destination is filtering data. I would identify which culprit it is and then work backwards to address it. If you need more specifics, post more details (source query, schemas, sample data, etc). It sounds like you have the concepts down so it's likely a data issue somewhere

Comment: The data flow task never goes yellow.  There are no transformations between the source and the destination.  I think I know what you are looking for.  The yellow warnings I've generally seen come from a column mapping problem.  Visual Studio doesn't give any indication , I can see, of a problem.  I'll see if I can get more specifics that make sense.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Look in your Output Window (Ctrl-Alt-O) after the package has executed. You might have an Error message hiding in there. If nothing else, look for Warnings and report back

Comment: Does your data flow consist of only a source and a destination or are there intervening steps?

Comment: Try establishing data viewers between consecutive steps in the data flow task, that might help you see after which step (if you have more than just source-destination) the Data Flow Task goes wrong. Also, isn't destination in write-protected area or is write-protected itself?

Comment: Some debugging steps that I would try: **1. Replace the flat file destination from the demographics package with a Union All. Also place data viewer. This should work, as you said you are able to see the data in the source ** 2. Next add a new destination component and 'follow the clicks' to create the connection new Connection manager (as opposed to creating a connection manager first, and then hooking it up to the destination component).

Comment: kyooryu has a good point about the protection level. Try creating the file on the local machine, if not already doing that.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help so far.  I rebuilt the package as part of a solution so I could use the debugging tools. Built the new connection manager by following the clicks.  Here is the only warning in the debug outpur: Warning: 0x80049304 at Export constituent with address file for import into ONE, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.  There are no steps between the data source and destination.

Comment: A data viewer between the source and destination dsplays good data in the proper columns and rows.  Both the data source and destination go yellow when run in debug.

Comment: We'll, I'll be.  The package is working.  I have no idea what changed to cause it to start working but think it came from rebuilding the package.  Possibly building the connection manager as part of the destination, instead of ahead of time.  Thanks all.

Comment: I am having exact same problem. I am running a ODBC and OLE DB connections from same data base using two sources and destinations. However this issue occurs with PNGP Native Postgres OLE DB Provider. There are no errors at all, not even with a Data Viewer detection. Simply no data flows in to destination flat file for OLE DB Connector. Preview shows nothing but the column headers. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the data to a tmp table in your db, if the data is saved there the issue is on the file connection, if not your query needs to be rewritten

Answer (score 0):

Verify the query columns you are executing on the tables are matching and data types are as expected in output ,  try putting all as string types initially and check if it works then apply correct data types after it executes successfully you can modify for data types as needed